# Save uiimage with custom format

Tags: iphone, uiimage, whatsapp

I want to save an image with ".wai" extension, for send it trough whatsapp.h
ow can I save the image with this format? 
The whatsapp site don't have a sample code, for more information this is the link (propbably visiting this link you understand my problem)

http://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/iphone/23559013

Comment: What happens if you just rename a `.jpg` or `.png` to `.wai` ? Could be as simple as that.

Answer (score 1):

```
NSData *pngData = UIImagePNGRepresentation(drawimg.image);
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *documentsPath = [paths objectAtIndex:0];                        //Get the docs directory
filePath = [documentsPath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"edited.wai"]; //Add the file name
[pngData writeToFile:filePath atomically:YES];
```